# Speech-To-Text IAM Authentication connection issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, ibm-watson

I have been using the Watson Speech-To-Text service for my unity3D hololens project. It was working great so I convinced my boss to get an account. I am trying to switch from my account to his. Mine used the CF authentication, his uses the IAM authentication. For some reason when trying to use his account, the connection instantly closes. I am testing it in the ExampleStreaming scene in the Watson SDK for Unity. Whenever I use the IAM Authetication I instantly get the OnListenClosed function with the State as Disconnected  right after the SendStart function. I switch it back to my old CF credentials and it works great!

Just wondering if anyone is familiar with this issue.
Thanks!

Comment: What version of Unity and the Watson SDK are you using? Also which region is your speech to text service instance?

Comment: Sorry I haven't been on here in a while. I was using unity 2018.1, so IAM authentication was incompatible. 

"Watson services have upgraded their hosts to TLS 1.2. The US South  region has a TLS 1.0 endpoint that will work for streaming but if you  are streaming in other regions you will need to use Unity 2018.2 and set  Scripting Runtime Version in Build Settings to .NET 4.x equivalent. In  lower versions of Unity you will need to create the Speech to Text  instance in US South."

So that is why it wasn't working for me. Now the CF authentication stopped working lol. Separate issue tho

Comment: You have probably already seen it here 
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk/issues/468
I think I will upgrade to Unity 2018.3 anyway, I was avoiding .2 because Unity had an issue with the camera taking photos.

Comment: OK good, so it is being tracked. Can you please post any error messages in the issue? Also config options if you have any (il2ccp, .net, scripting runtime, etc)

Comment: sure! thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the service endpoint url associated with your boss' IAM credentials. The service endpoint for IAM Key instances changes with regions, and it might not match your old one.

Comment: Thank you for your response, and sorry for my delayed response to your response. Yea I made sure to have the correct service URL, and I kept the Iam Url blank (it defaults to https://iam.bluemix.net/identity/token). I tested the watson assistant with the Iam service credentials and it worked for me. So it must be an issue with the WSconnecter. For now I just created a space in US south and put my speech-to-text under that so I can still use the CF credentials. I will do some more testing when I have time because I think they plan on migrating all regions at some point.

Comment: If you are using a library or a SDK then that might not have implemented IAM authentication.